# Regexp minimal match on javascript minified file

Tags: javascript, regex

I've a minified file. The main particularity is there is only one line.

this could be an extract:

```
bla();someothercode('resources/images/myPicture1.png'),someothercode('resources/images/myPicture2.png'),someothercode('resources/images/myPicture3.png');plop();
```

I tried to catch with `/\/(.*\.png)` and I obtain:

```
myPicture1.png'),someothercode('resources/images/myPicture2.png'),someothercode('resources/images/myPicture3.png
```

instead of many result as:

```
[myPicture1.png, myPicture2.png, myPicture3.png]
```

How do I match all the pngs separately?

Comment: `.*?` - un-greedy match.

Comment: `.*?` does not work. Also I do not get the negative vote... anyway already few great answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
\/([^\/]*\.png)
```

Here, `\/` matches `/` and then `([^\/]*\.png)` matches and captures the name of the PNG (as `[^\/]*` matches 0 or more characters other than `/`, the matches returned are as expected, and the expected values are inside Group 1).

See code:

```js
var re = /\/([^\/]*\.png)/g; 
var str = 'bla();someothercode(\'resources/images/myPicture1.png\'),someothercode(\'resources/images/myPicture2.png\'),someothercode(\'resources/images/myPicture3.png\');plop();';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.write(m[1] + "<br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To catch all "words" that end in `.png`, you can say:

```
/\b[^\/]+\.png/g
```

This will find filenames whether or not there is a preceding `/`.

```js
var st = "bla();someothercode('resources/images/myPicture1.png'),someothercode('resources/images/myPicture2.png'),someothercode('resources/images/myPicture3.png');plop();";

var matches = st.match(/\b[^\/]+\.png/g);

console.log(matches);
```